# How to find invertible $P$ such that $PAP^{-1}$ is upper triangular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

I know that $A$ is similar to a Jordan Normal Form matrix, but I'm struggling to find and understand a method to work out what $P$ is (NOT the JNF matrix that $A$ is similar to)

EDIT: I'm dealing with complex matrices.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry, forgot to put on the post that I'm working with complex matrices. Does this make a difference?

Comment: If just upper triangular then there are many such matrices. [Schur triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition), for example, can be done by unitary change of basis.

Comment: @A.G. He's looking at Jordan form, but he's interested in finding the $P$ as opposed to the Jordan-form matrix $J$.

Comment: @hhattiecc what you need are the generalized eigenvectors, as explained [in this slide show](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~moose/240S2013/slides7-31.pdf) and in example 7 [here](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~spl/old_courses/304_fall_2008/handouts/jordan.pdf)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh, I see. It is a long story to tell how to find a transformation matrix in general. It is used to be about one lecture to talk about the nilpotent case first.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the Jordan form $J$ of $A$, then the equation $PAP^{-1}=J$ gives
$PA=JP$, which is a system of $n^2$ linear equations in the entries (as variables) of $P$, together with the condition that $\det(P)\neq 0$. This system of linear equations can be solved easily. Of course, one could also compute the generalized eigenvectors. A computation of the Jordan form usually comes together with these generalized eigenvectors (try it in Maple or Mathematica or any other CAS). The computation how to find such transformation matrix $P$ has been done already at MSE for many examples, e.g., see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2058079/finding-p-in-a-p-1jp-jordan-form?rq=1).